# How can I break line on R's setwd() command?

Tags: r

I try to keep all my R script lines under 80 characters. This can prove to be a challenge whenever strings are involved, but usually just breaking lines without using any special character works, like this:

```
plot(x, y, main = "some reeeealy long title, so long that
                   I need to break it into several lines
                   in order to satisfy my ****-retentive
                   self.")
```

However, some functions such as `setwd()` just won't let me do this. For example, running

```
setwd("/folder/another folder/yet another folder/
      what are you doing, hiding pr0n?/I think I've made my point/")
```

Returns the following error:

```
Error in setwd("/folder/another folder/yet another folder/\n
      what are you doing, hiding pr0n?/I think I've made my point/") : 
cannot change working directory
```

I've tried braking line on different points other than at the slash character, but I couldn't get it to work. The only workaround I could find was running

```
setwd(paste("/folder/another folder/yet another folder/",
            "what are you doing, hiding pr0n?/I think I've made my point/",
            sep = "")
```

Which works, but seems like a lot of mess just in order to respect some self-defined rule.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: As a side comment, I almost always believe it is a bad idea to put `setwd()` in your code. Instead, you should do this in other ways before you run any code, e.g. start R in that directory so you do not need to `setwd()` inside the code; `setwd()` makes your code less portable.

Comment: That's true, Yihui, thanks for the reminder. ;) But I don't know if this works outside of *nix environments (on Windows, to be explicit), does it?

Comment: You can also run R in a command window under Windows just like you do under *nix, but I guess people rarely do that (they use RGui instead), so I recommend always setting the working directory before running code which involves with files (I vaguely remember it is `File-->Change dir`).

Comment: Another point of view: when I work in Windows, I use `setwd` in my code all the time, because it makes changing the directory (as described above) much faster and easier to remember to do.  In some sense, I feel this makes the code more portable; I can give it to a client and tell them to just change that first line, and then the rest of it works, rather than having to tell them how to use the menus.  There's a question somewhere on SO about getting R to change to the directory of a currently open script, which would be really nice, but as I recall, no method was found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `paste` is the only way I can think of, however, in this special case, `file.path` is a better choice than `paste` as it provides the right separation character for your platform automatically.

```
file.path("/folder", "another folder", "yet another folder",
            "what are you doing, hiding pr0n?",
            "I think I've made my point")
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste them together as in:

```
x <-paste("/folder/another folder/yet another folder/",
      "what are you doing, hiding pr0n?/I think I've made my point/",
      "and for good measure/", sep="")
setwd(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegant ways to achieve this (or at least ones I can think of right now):

1. Add an alias to the directory so you can reference them easier in your R script. For example, my projects reside in `~/Documents/Work/Active Projects/Project name/code/` but I have a simple alias such that I can just use `~/code/project name/` when I reference such files/data.
2. You can store a lot in your `options()` in a `.rprofile`. Example: `options(Path='/really/long/path/to/something')`. Then you can just use `setwd(getOption('Path'))`

Answer (score 1):

Another hack: make up a `setwd2` function that strips newlines and adjoining whitespace (or, at your peril, masks the built-in `setwd` function ... store it in your profile etc.

```
setwd2 <- function(dir,debug=TRUE) {
  setwd(gsub("\\n *","",dir))
}
```

Test:

```
setwd2("tmp/
      tmp/
      tmp")
```